# How to deserialize json to enum in rust?

Tags: json, rust, deserialization, serde

I have string "040000" and I want to get a variant of this enum:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug, Clone, JsonSchema)]
pub enum GitCreateTreeRequestMode {
    #[serde(rename = "040000")]
    SubdirectoryTree,
    #[serde(rename = "100644")]
    FileBlob,
    #[serde(rename = "100755")]
    ExecutableBlob,
    #[serde(rename = "120000")]
    SymlinkPathBlob,
    #[serde(rename = "160000")]
    SubmoduleCommit,
    #[serde(rename = "")]
    Noop,
    #[serde(other)]
    FallthroughString,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```rust
let mode_string = "040000";
let mode: GitCreateTreeRequestMode = serde_json::from_str(&format!(r#"{}"#, mode_string)).unwrap();
```

Or

```
let mode_string = "040000";
let mode: GitCreateTreeRequestMode = serde_json::from_str(&format!("\"{}\"", mode_string)).unwrap();
```